# How to deny direct HTTP(S) access from browser but allow from iframe

Tags: apache, authentication, iframe

I have 2 applications on the same host:

1. 80 port: Apache serves js/html content for NodeJS backend, no authentication.
2. 8080 port: Angular/Java app, with authentication.

I already embedded 1 to 2 through `iframe`.

Is it possible to deny access to 1 directly, just typing host name in a browser, but allow from 2?

Comment: Here is [solution from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25219088/17782348) with Apache `.htaccess` that helps me.